# Is it possible to use documentclass like wileySix as book template in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, document-class

I would like to use a different template than the default defined for documentclass: book such as the `wileySix`. Would that be possible? Maybe by including `in_header: file.tex` and inside such file I could define `\documentclass{wileySix}`?

Then basically I have here two question:

1. Would a pdf document created from R Markdown be compatible with different documentclass for books?
2. and if the answer is "yes, by declaring the `\documentclass` inside a file.tex and calling/including it by your YAML", as I have never used the file.tex, how would I could do that? any help is very welcome

Comment: Thanks @Gregor for the editing corrections.